# 64 bits architecture optimization

Tags: c++, c, performance, 32bit-64bit

I'm testing a function that calculates the XOR of two char buffers. In order to increase the speed, I'm checking the speed of doing with a integer pointer (32 bits) and long long integer pointer (64 bits). I use the function with a char pointer for reference. Of course, I'm testing on a 64bits machine.

But I'm not having the results that I expected. I'm trying with these 3 functions at the end. When I compare "XOR_Diff_Char" with "XOR_Diff_Int", I get an increase of speed around 3x, because the function "_Int" iterates 4 times less in the main "for". But when I compare "XOR_Diff_Int" with "XOR_Diff_QWORD", the improvement is arount 5-10%, really slower than I expected because the main "for" iterates 2x times less in "_QWORD" than in "_Int". I had tried (in order to compare speeds) to compile with different flags, between -O0 and -O3, but I found no differences.

I use g++ 4.9.2-10 compiler under Debian 64bits. Do I have to put another flag? Do I suppose something and I'm wrong? Is the compiler so good that doesn't matter if you use 32 or 64 bits?

```
/////////////////////////////////
int XOR_Diff_Int(char *pBuffIn1, char *pBuffIn2, char *pBuffOut, unsigned int sizeBuff)
{      
    int i = 0;

    /* Check errors ... */ 

    int *pBuff1 = (int*)pBuffIn1;
    int *pBuff2 = (int*)pBuffIn2;
    int *pOut = (int*)pBuffOut;

    unsigned int sizeInt = (sizeBuff/sizeof(int));
    unsigned int modInt = sizeBuff-(sizeBuff%sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < sizeInt;  i++, pBuff1++, pBuff2++, pOut++)
        *pOut = *pBuff1 ^ *pBuff2;

    // If size is not sizeof(int) multiple
    for (i = modInt; i < sizeBuff;  i++)
        pBuffOut[i] = pBuffIn1[i] ^ pBuffIn2[i];

    return sizeBuff;
}

/////////////////////////////////
int XOR_Diff_Char(char *pBuffIn1, char *pBuffIn2, char *pBuffOut, unsigned int sizeBuff)
{      
    int i = 0;

    /* Check errors ... */ 

    for (i = 0; i < sizeBuff;  i++)
        pBuffOut[i] = pBuffIn1[i] ^ pBuffIn2[i];

    return 1;
}


/////////////////////////////////
int XOR_Diff_QWORD(char *pBuffIn1, char *pBuffIn2, char *pBuffOut, unsigned int sizeBuff)
{      
    int i = 0;

    /* Check errors ... */ 

    long long int *pBuff1 = (long long int*)pBuffIn1;
    long long int *pBuff2 = (long long int*)pBuffIn2;
    long long int *pOut = (long long int*)pBuffOut;

    unsigned int sizeLong = (sizeBuff/sizeof(long long int));
    unsigned int modLong = sizeBuff-(sizeBuff%sizeof(long long int));

    for (i = 0; i < sizeLong;  i++, pBuff1++, pBuff2++, pOut++)
        *pOut = *pBuff1 ^ *pBuff2;

    // If size is not sizeof(long long int) multiple
    for (i = modLong; i < sizeBuff;  i++)
        pBuffOut[i] = pBuffIn1[i] ^ pBuffIn2[i];

    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I was using the gcov utility, and I can see that the function with _QWORD executes the half number of iterations than _Int, so the speed should be the double (despite overhead of functions and so on). So I understand less why the speed is similar in both cases. For testing, I just using something as simple as

```
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
count = XOR_Diff_Int(pDataIn, prevData, pOut, SIZE);
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
```

changing "_Int" for "_QWORD" and recompiling for both types of test.

**EDIT 2:**

I don't know so much about assembler, but I compared both function (the main "for"), and I got this:

```
// 64bits XOR
    movq    (%rsi,%r8,8), %r9
    xorq    (%rdi,%r8,8), %r9
    movq    %r9, (%rdx,%r8,8)
    addq    $1, %r8
    cmpl    %r8d, %ecx
    ja  .L8

// 32bits XOR
    movl    (%rsi,%r8,4), %r9d
    xorl    (%rdi,%r8,4), %r9d
    movl    %r9d, (%rdx,%r8,4)
    addq    $1, %r8
    cmpl    %r8d, %ecx
    jg  .L8
```

So I understand that the 64bits case is faster because uses 8 bytes instructions. I think that is not a "instructions" problems, but the operating system or something like that. At the moment I haven't anymore idea about this.

Comment: Can you specify your compile parameters to replicate this?

Comment: really there is a lot going on here, we would probably need to see the compiler/version optimization level, and arch to even guess... but you could look at assembled output for a clue... -s

Comment: Cache size doesn't double when you move from 32-bit to 64-bit, memory bandwidth doesn't either. Cache actually becomes less efficient, so counting loop iterations isn't always the right metric. Run it through an actual profiler and look at cache activity if you want to do this the right way.

Comment: If you have to ask that, you might want to see at the generated assembly code for these variations.

Comment: @SidharthN.Kashyap I only use the optimization -O parameter (-O0, -O1, -O2 and -O3). By default, the compiler uses -m64

Comment: You may also want to look at implicit conversions for numeric types. Generally, the base is type `int` and other values undergo implicit conversion from type `int` (generally meaning that `int` will be the most efficient type, not requiring any conversion) This will vary by platform and compiler, but it is something to investigate that my impact your `xor` performance and results. With `gcc >= 4.6` you also have `-Ofast` optimization available.

Comment: Your code violates the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule -> undefined behaviour. The question also lacks information. How do you profile? What are the buffers? how are they aligned? etc. Also which of the two different languages C or C++ is it?

Comment: @GradyPlayer I have been looking in the assembled code, but I don't know so much about this to check the differences

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin With the -Ofast flag I obtain the same result as -O3

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. I understand that if I use a 64 bit architecture, the optimal witdh is 64 bits, but maybe I'm wrong. In fact, with a 64bits vars the function is faster, but not as faster as I would like.

Comment: What processor is this? Older processors don't handle misalignment very well. So if going to 64 bits causes misalignment, it can backfire.

Comment: `long long int *pBuff1 = (long long int*)pBuffIn1;` may render `pBuff1` to point to an unaligned address.  This is UB and even if allowed, likely inefficient to access `long long` via this pointer.  To make efficient, the pointers should be aligned when using `pBuffOut[i] = pBuffIn1[i] ^ pBuffIn2[i];`.  If not able to align use other code, perhaps narrow types until devolving to `byte` width.

Comment: The array is defined inside a struct `struct DATA_t {
 unsigned char p[SIZE_DATA];
} __attribute__((aligned(8))) ;`. In fact, I had tried with differents alignments and packed. If I had a align mistake, I'll get a segmentation fault, won't I?

Comment: @Mysticial I had tried in a Intel i5 and in a Virtual Machine, with similar results and without problems with alignments

Comment: x86 does not segfault on misalignment (with some exceptions in SIMD). But it will result in a pretty severe performance penalty on older processors. Btw, "Intel i5" doesn't tell me anything because every Intel architecture for the past 7 years have been branded as "i5" (among others).

Comment: @Mysticial I had tried also in a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v3 @ 3.50GHz, I think is not so old processor. Of course, the results are the same.

Comment: Did you look at the assembly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you've tried to do is outsmart the compiler. The compiler won.

Given the following simple function:

```
void f(const char* lhs, const char* rhs, char* out, size_t sz)
{      
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i )
        out[i] = lhs[i] ^ rhs[i];
}
```

and compiling with GCC with `-O3 -Wall`, the compiler spits out [nearly 300 lines of assembler](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-O3+-Wall',source:'++++%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0A++++void+f(const+char*+lhs,+const+char*+rhs,+char*+out,+size_t+sz)%0A++++%7B++++++%0A++++++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+%2B%2Bi+)%0A++++++++++++out%5Bi%5D+%3D+lhs%5Bi%5D+%5E+rhs%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
f(char const*, char const*, char*, unsigned long):
        testq   %rcx, %rcx
        je      .L38
        leaq    16(%rdi), %rax
        leaq    16(%rdx), %r9
        cmpq    %rax, %rdx
        setnb   %r8b
        cmpq    %r9, %rdi
        setnb   %al
        orl     %eax, %r8d
        leaq    16(%rsi), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rdx
        setnb   %r10b
        cmpq    %r9, %rsi
        setnb   %al
        orl     %r10d, %eax
        testb   %al, %r8b
        je      .L3
        cmpq    $19, %rcx
        jbe     .L3
        movq    %rdi, %r8
        pushq   %r13
        pushq   %r12
        negq    %r8
        pushq   %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        andl    $15, %r8d
        cmpq    %rcx, %r8
        cmova   %rcx, %r8
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testq   %r8, %r8
        je      .L4
        movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
        xorb    (%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $1, %r8
        movb    %al, (%rdx)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  1(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    1(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $2, %r8
        movb    %al, 1(%rdx)
        je      .L16
        movzbl  2(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    2(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $3, %r8
        movb    %al, 2(%rdx)
        je      .L17
        movzbl  3(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    3(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $4, %r8
        movb    %al, 3(%rdx)
        je      .L18
        movzbl  4(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    4(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $5, %r8
        movb    %al, 4(%rdx)
        je      .L19
        movzbl  5(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    5(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $6, %r8
        movb    %al, 5(%rdx)
        je      .L20
        movzbl  6(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    6(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $7, %r8
        movb    %al, 6(%rdx)
        je      .L21
        movzbl  7(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    7(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $8, %r8
        movb    %al, 7(%rdx)
        je      .L22
        movzbl  8(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    8(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $9, %r8
        movb    %al, 8(%rdx)
        je      .L23
        movzbl  9(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    9(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $10, %r8
        movb    %al, 9(%rdx)
        je      .L24
        movzbl  10(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    10(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $11, %r8
        movb    %al, 10(%rdx)
        je      .L25
        movzbl  11(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    11(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $12, %r8
        movb    %al, 11(%rdx)
        je      .L26
        movzbl  12(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    12(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $13, %r8
        movb    %al, 12(%rdx)
        je      .L27
        movzbl  13(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    13(%rsi), %al
        cmpq    $14, %r8
        movb    %al, 13(%rdx)
        je      .L28
        movzbl  14(%rdi), %eax
        xorb    14(%rsi), %al
        movb    %al, 14(%rdx)
        movl    $15, %eax
.L4:
        movq    %rcx, %r11
        leaq    -1(%rcx), %r10
        subq    %r8, %r11
        leaq    -16(%r11), %r9
        subq    %r8, %r10
        shrq    $4, %r9
        addq    $1, %r9
        movq    %r9, %rbx
        salq    $4, %rbx
        cmpq    $14, %r10
        jbe     .L6
        leaq    (%rdi,%r8), %r13
        leaq    (%rsi,%r8), %r12
        xorl    %r10d, %r10d
        addq    %rdx, %r8
        xorl    %ebp, %ebp
.L8:
        movdqu  (%r12,%r10), %xmm0
        addq    $1, %rbp
        pxor    0(%r13,%r10), %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, (%r8,%r10)
        addq    $16, %r10
        cmpq    %r9, %rbp
        jb      .L8
        addq    %rbx, %rax
        cmpq    %rbx, %r11
        je      .L1
.L6:
        movzbl  (%rsi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    (%rdi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, (%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    1(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  1(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    1(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 1(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    2(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  2(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    2(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 2(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    3(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  3(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    3(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 3(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    4(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  4(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    4(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 4(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    5(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  5(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    5(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 5(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    6(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  6(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    6(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 6(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    7(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  7(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    7(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 7(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    8(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  8(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    8(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 8(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    9(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  9(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    9(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 9(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    10(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  10(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    10(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 10(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    11(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  11(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    11(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 11(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    12(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  12(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    12(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 12(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    13(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  13(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    13(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 13(%rdx,%rax)
        leaq    14(%rax), %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  14(%rdi,%rax), %ecx
        xorb    14(%rsi,%rax), %cl
        movb    %cl, 14(%rdx,%rax)
.L1:
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r13
.L38:
        rep ret
.L3:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L13:
        movzbl  (%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    (%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, (%rdx,%rax)
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jne     .L13
        rep ret
.L28:
        movl    $14, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L15:
        movl    $1, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L16:
        movl    $2, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L17:
        movl    $3, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L18:
        movl    $4, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L19:
        movl    $5, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L20:
        movl    $6, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L21:
        movl    $7, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L22:
        movl    $8, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L23:
        movl    $9, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L24:
        movl    $10, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L25:
        movl    $11, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L26:
        movl    $12, %eax
        jmp     .L4
.L27:
        movl    $13, %eax
        jmp     .L4
```

It does better if we add [`-march=native -mtune=native`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dnative+-mtune%3Dnative',source:'++++%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0A++++void+f(const+char*+lhs,+const+char*+rhs,+char*+out,+size_t+sz)%0A++++%7B++++++%0A++++++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+%2B%2Bi+)%0A++++++++++++out%5Bi%5D+%3D+lhs%5Bi%5D+%5E+rhs%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

The compiler has done its own striding, and done a much better job at it than it can with the variants you are producing.

```
void f(const char* lhs, const char* rhs, char* out, size_t sz)
{
    const int* ilhs = (const int*)lhs;
    const int* irhs = (const int*)rhs;
    int* iout = (int*)out;

    const size_t isz = (sz / sizeof(*ilhs));
    const size_t imod = (isz * sizeof(*ilhs));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < isz; ++i)
        *(iout++) = *(ilhs++) ^ *(irhs)++;

    for (size_t i = imod; i < sz; ++i)
        out[i] = lhs[i] ^ rhs[i];
}
```

This produces [almost 400 lines of assembler](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-O3+-Wall',sourcez:AQ4YgSwOwYwGwK4BMCmwA8MDOAXJqAzAPgCgTRgA3AewiWAIAoZqpdgYALAQwCcAqYHE5YANB1bsufQbxHjpA4NQQ5xWCAC8UAfRzAsmgJTlQAb1MUQLNvug5BEYVmABeYM0l2oDo84DcllY27PaOci7unrbAYUYRgVagYbEq%2BlFxaYFBFCH6Gtp6sYZuHiUA9AZaKNRM/E4iRkaJSRIxBbp2ALbU9Bklgh21jPXOTdmtDNS8ZdVFEKUADP6xGMWaKwDUmxAmkxT8jBBp20alhw1Yp8AAesAXEUbbE60E07OFdqUQPUgrC%2BgDBtgNtdjlWmkANoQAC6pWc0LhdwiiJaIAAvkAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

```
f(char const*, char const*, char*, unsigned long):
        movq    %rcx, %r8
        pushq   %r15
        pushq   %r14
        shrq    $2, %r8
        pushq   %r13
        pushq   %r12
        testq   %r8, %r8
        pushq   %rbp
        leaq    0(,%r8,4), %rax
        pushq   %rbx
        je      .L11
        leaq    16(%rsi), %r9
        leaq    16(%rdx), %r10
        cmpq    %r9, %rdx
        setnb   %r11b
        cmpq    %r10, %rsi
        setnb   %r9b
        orl     %r11d, %r9d
        cmpq    $8, %r8
        seta    %r11b
        testb   %r11b, %r9b
        je      .L4
        leaq    16(%rdi), %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %rdx
        setnb   %r11b
        cmpq    %r10, %rdi
        setnb   %r9b
        orb     %r9b, %r11b
        je      .L4
        movq    %rdi, %r9
        andl    $15, %r9d
        shrq    $2, %r9
        negq    %r9
        andl    $3, %r9d
        cmpq    %r8, %r9
        cmova   %r8, %r9
        testq   %r9, %r9
        je      .L25
        movl    (%rdi), %r10d
        xorl    (%rsi), %r10d
        cmpq    $1, %r9
        leaq    4(%rdx), %r13
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rbp
        leaq    4(%rsi), %rbx
        movl    %r10d, (%rdx)
        movl    $1, %r10d
        je      .L5
        movl    4(%rdi), %r10d
        xorl    4(%rsi), %r10d
        cmpq    $2, %r9
        leaq    8(%rdx), %r13
        leaq    8(%rdi), %rbp
        leaq    8(%rsi), %rbx
        movl    %r10d, 4(%rdx)
        movl    $2, %r10d
        je      .L5
        movl    8(%rdi), %r10d
        xorl    8(%rsi), %r10d
        leaq    12(%rdx), %r13
        leaq    12(%rdi), %rbp
        leaq    12(%rsi), %rbx
        movl    %r10d, 8(%rdx)
        movl    $3, %r10d
.L5:
        movq    %r8, %r15
        movq    %rax, -16(%rsp)
        subq    %r9, %r15
        salq    $2, %r9
        leaq    -4(%r15), %r11
        leaq    (%rsi,%r9), %r12
        movq    %r15, -24(%rsp)
        leaq    (%rdi,%r9), %r15
        addq    %rdx, %r9
        shrq    $2, %r11
        movq    %r12, -40(%rsp)
        movq    %r9, -32(%rsp)
        addq    $1, %r11
        xorl    %r9d, %r9d
        xorl    %r12d, %r12d
        leaq    0(,%r11,4), %r14
.L8:
        movq    -40(%rsp), %rax
        addq    $1, %r12
        movdqu  (%rax,%r9), %xmm0
        movq    -32(%rsp), %rax
        pxor    (%r15,%r9), %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, (%rax,%r9)
        addq    $16, %r9
        cmpq    %r11, %r12
        jb      .L8
        leaq    0(,%r14,4), %r9
        addq    %r14, %r10
        movq    -16(%rsp), %rax
        addq    %r9, %rbp
        addq    %r9, %rbx
        addq    %r9, %r13
        cmpq    %r14, -24(%rsp)
        je      .L11
        movl    0(%rbp), %r9d
        xorl    (%rbx), %r9d
        movl    %r9d, 0(%r13)
        leaq    1(%r10), %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %r8
        jbe     .L11
        movl    4(%rbp), %r9d
        xorl    4(%rbx), %r9d
        addq    $2, %r10
        cmpq    %r10, %r8
        movl    %r9d, 4(%r13)
        jbe     .L11
        movl    8(%rbp), %r9d
        xorl    8(%rbx), %r9d
        movl    %r9d, 8(%r13)
.L11:
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        leaq    16(%rax), %r9
        leaq    (%rsi,%rax), %rbx
        movq    %rcx, %r11
        leaq    (%rdx,%rax), %rbp
        subq    %rax, %r11
        leaq    (%rdi,%rax), %r10
        leaq    (%rdx,%r9), %r12
        leaq    (%rdi,%r9), %r13
        cmpq    %rbx, %r12
        setbe   %bl
        addq    %rsi, %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %rbp
        setnb   %r9b
        orl     %r9d, %ebx
        cmpq    %r12, %r10
        setnb   %r12b
        cmpq    %r13, %rbp
        setnb   %r9b
        orl     %r12d, %r9d
        testb   %r9b, %bl
        je      .L24
        cmpq    $19, %r11
        jbe     .L24
        negq    %r10
        movq    %rax, %r9
        andl    $15, %r10d
        cmpq    %r11, %r10
        cmova   %r11, %r10
        testq   %r10, %r10
        je      .L15
        movzbl  (%rdi,%r8,4), %r9d
        xorb    (%rsi,%r8,4), %r9b
        cmpq    $1, %r10
        movb    %r9b, (%rdx,%r8,4)
        leaq    1(%rax), %r9
        je      .L15
        movzbl  1(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    2(%rax), %r9
        xorb    1(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $2, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 1(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  2(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    3(%rax), %r9
        xorb    2(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $3, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 2(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  3(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    4(%rax), %r9
        xorb    3(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $4, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 3(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  4(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    5(%rax), %r9
        xorb    4(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $5, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 4(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  5(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    6(%rax), %r9
        xorb    5(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $6, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 5(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  6(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    7(%rax), %r9
        xorb    6(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $7, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 6(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  7(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    8(%rax), %r9
        xorb    7(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $8, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 7(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  8(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    9(%rax), %r9
        xorb    8(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $9, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 8(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  9(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    10(%rax), %r9
        xorb    9(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $10, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 9(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  10(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    11(%rax), %r9
        xorb    10(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $11, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 10(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  11(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    12(%rax), %r9
        xorb    11(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $12, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 11(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  12(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    13(%rax), %r9
        xorb    12(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $13, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 12(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  13(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    14(%rax), %r9
        xorb    13(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        cmpq    $14, %r10
        movb    %r8b, 13(%rdx,%rax)
        je      .L15
        movzbl  14(%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        leaq    15(%rax), %r9
        xorb    14(%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, 14(%rdx,%rax)
.L15:
        movq    %r11, %rbp
        leaq    -1(%r11), %r8
        subq    %r10, %rbp
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rbx
        subq    %r10, %r8
        shrq    $4, %rbx
        addq    $1, %rbx
        movq    %rbx, %r12
        salq    $4, %r12
        cmpq    $14, %r8
        jbe     .L17
        addq    %r10, %rax
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        xorl    %r10d, %r10d
        leaq    (%rdi,%rax), %r13
        leaq    (%rsi,%rax), %r11
        addq    %rdx, %rax
.L19:
        movdqu  (%r11,%r8), %xmm0
        addq    $1, %r10
        pxor    0(%r13,%r8), %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, (%rax,%r8)
        addq    $16, %r8
        cmpq    %rbx, %r10
        jb      .L19
        addq    %r12, %r9
        cmpq    %r12, %rbp
        je      .L1
.L17:
        movzbl  (%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    (%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, (%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    1(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  1(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    1(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 1(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    2(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  2(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    2(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 2(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    3(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  3(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    3(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 3(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    4(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  4(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    4(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 4(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    5(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  5(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    5(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 5(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    6(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  6(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    6(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 6(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    7(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  7(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    7(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 7(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    8(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  8(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    8(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 8(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    9(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  9(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    9(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 9(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    10(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  10(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    10(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 10(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    11(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  11(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    11(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 11(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    12(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  12(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    12(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 12(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    13(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  13(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    13(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 13(%rdx,%r9)
        leaq    14(%r9), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jbe     .L1
        movzbl  14(%rdi,%r9), %eax
        xorb    14(%rsi,%r9), %al
        movb    %al, 14(%rdx,%r9)
.L1:
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r13
        popq    %r14
        popq    %r15
        ret
.L24:
        movzbl  (%rdi,%rax), %r8d
        xorb    (%rsi,%rax), %r8b
        movb    %r8b, (%rdx,%rax)
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jne     .L24
        jmp     .L1
.L25:
        movq    %rdx, %r13
        movq    %rsi, %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbp
        xorl    %r10d, %r10d
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
        xorl    %r9d, %r9d
.L13:
        movl    (%rdi,%r9,4), %r10d
        xorl    (%rsi,%r9,4), %r10d
        movl    %r10d, (%rdx,%r9,4)
        addq    $1, %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %r8
        jne     .L13
        jmp     .L11
```

In the compiler's version of the simple function, there's an immediate and simple test for sz being zero:

```
f(char const*, char const*, char*, unsigned long):
    testq   %rcx, %rcx
    je      .L38
```

In your version, the compiler hasn't recognized that you're making an attempt at striding, and the code has to walk through a number of steps to get there:

```
f(char const*, char const*, char*, unsigned long):
    movq    %rcx, %r8
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    shrq    $2, %r8
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    testq   %r8, %r8
    pushq   %rbp
    leaq    0(,%r8,4), %rax
    pushq   %rbx
    je      .L11
...
.L11:
    cmpq    %rax, %rcx
    jbe     .L1    ...
.L1:
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r13
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    ret
```

We also have quite a lot of register spill here keeping track of all these variables.

Lets compare a couple of early blocks of the code:

Compiler:

```
    leaq    16(%rdi), %rax
    leaq    16(%rdx), %r9
    cmpq    %rax, %rdx
    setnb   %r8b
    cmpq    %r9, %rdi
    setnb   %al
    orl     %eax, %r8d
    leaq    16(%rsi), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rdx
    setnb   %r10b
    cmpq    %r9, %rsi
    setnb   %al
    orl     %r10d, %eax
    testb   %al, %r8b
    je      .L3
    cmpq    $19, %rcx
    jbe     .L3
    movq    %rdi, %r8
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    negq    %r8
    pushq   %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    andl    $15, %r8d
    cmpq    %rcx, %r8
    cmova   %rcx, %r8
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testq   %r8, %r8
    je      .L4
```

Yours:

```
    leaq    16(%rsi), %r9
    leaq    16(%rdx), %r10
    cmpq    %r9, %rdx
    setnb   %r11b
    cmpq    %r10, %rsi
    setnb   %r9b
    orl     %r11d, %r9d
    cmpq    $8, %r8
    seta    %r11b
    testb   %r11b, %r9b
    je      .L4
    leaq    16(%rdi), %r9
    cmpq    %r9, %rdx
    setnb   %r11b
    cmpq    %r10, %rdi
    setnb   %r9b
    orb     %r9b, %r11b
    je      .L4
    movq    %rdi, %r9
    andl    $15, %r9d
    shrq    $2, %r9
    negq    %r9
    andl    $3, %r9d
    cmpq    %r8, %r9
    cmova   %r8, %r9
    testq   %r9, %r9
    je      .L25
```

We can see here that the compiler is just having to emit more instructions for each operation than it was producing by itself for the original version.

Comment: (1/2) Well, of course I am not outsmart than compiler, I only want to ease its work. The compiler cannot know if I can do a 8byte XOR or it have to do char by char. In fact, when I compare a char by char function and the 64bits function, the first is 4x slower than second, so I think that I'm more or less on the way. I think that the extra instructions due to declaring extra variables are compensated when you process large arrays (my case), so the optimization have to be in the main "for" where the XOR is executed.

Comment: (2/2) If the CPU can execute a XOR in one cycle, and you can reduce the number of iterations of the "for", it is logical to think that the time will be reduce. What you think? I use your code to compare it with my code (with -O2), and I get the same that with my compiler, the same 4 assembled instructions. Many thanks for your comments and your time!